# Hoe put searchbar in each component of UIPickerview? and how perform searching in each related SearchBar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Actually i used the pickerView for display My database value containing Name, SSN, Research Area etc. Now I need to search in each component of pickerview, like Name,SSN using SearchBar is it Possible?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to filter the rows of the components when the searchtext changed. 
You can have a NSArray for each component to populate it with: In `– searchBar:textDidChange:` you can check which entries in your arrays fit to the search text and add it to a array, that you will use to fill the picker. Don't forget to either call `[aPickerView reloadAllComponents]` or `[aPickerView reloadComponent:i]`, this will tell the picker to draw itself again.